# FFMPEG - Dynamically enable a watermark depending on a video's duration

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I have code to add a watermark to a folder's videos starting on minute 3 but I'd want it to add the watermark in intervals, for example, each 1/3 of the video's duration, how could I achieve this?

```
for %%I in ("path\\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i Watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/10[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-3:enable='between(t,3*60,3*60+3)'[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -codec:a copy "path\%%~nI.mp4"
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get duration using `ffprobe`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration):

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

Divide resulting duration by 3 or multiply by 0.3 to get 1/3 duration. Use this value for the `enable` option in your `ffmpeg` command:

```
enable='between(t,$duration,$duration*2)'
```

Comment: Thank you! this seems to be the answer to my issue, although I don't really know how to store the duration, I try running the code with the ffprobe implemented but I get an "Undefined constant or missing '('" in the enable section, I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me how or at least redirect me to somewhere where I could learn how to do it.

Comment: @NeoHerakles Unfortunately I can only provide you the `ff*` commands to achieve what you want: you'll have to figure out the Widows batch scripting, because as a Linux user I have no experience with that. Search for *Windows batch variable*. Perhaps someone can [edit] this answer or add their own with the batch side of things.